# Use symlink to move directory created by .deb package - will anything break?

Tags: symlink, dpkg

Sometimes it seems useful to shift package's directories around between tmpfs / flash memory or ssd / hard disk.  To manage flash lifetime, disk spin-up, or just free space.

If you replace a directory used by a package with a symlink, will the package manager not become confused at times?  E.g. consider debsums...

Would bind-mounts would hide it better instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[dpkg is apparently intended to support this](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=626203#10).

On the other hand, I believe `systemd` generally does not consider supporting symlinks like this.  E.g. I am now seeing a warning on boot, when `/var/log` is a symlink:

```
systemd-tmpfiles[432]: "/var/log" already exists and is not a directory.
```

This is due to `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf`.  As I understand it, this is set up as part of a concept that you can somehow boot `/usr` and have the rest of the system state initialized automatically.  E.g. that if you simply wipe /etc and reboot, the system would be restored to system default settings.

Another caveat - in case you're migrating from *nested* bind mounts.  Make sure to take care of dependencies.  At boot time mounts are normally ordered automatically, which is great.  But it doesn't seem to magically work out, if mounts are depending on each other through symlinks instead of directly.  (I believe this mounting at boot time was done by systemd).

Possible reasons for wanting to use symlinks were

- dpkg won't be able to handle them gracefully, e.g. if a directory is changed on upgrade.
- They're treated as separate by `fatrace`, so it is harder to monitor writes to individual devices.  (Technically this is not exactly the fault of `fatrace`; it is more a quirk of the kernel interface it uses).
- They're not great in `df`.  And `icinga`'s disk-space monitoring will alarm if the bind-mounted directory is not world-readable.
- If you try to bind-mount parts of a tmpfs, [you're going down a rabbit-hole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216472/bind-mounts-by-systemd-dont-magically-work-with-systemd-tmpfiles); you'll need a custom shell script which creates the directories first.